# Web AppBuilder Developer Edition - "this" Keyword Conflict with Button Element

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I created a `button` element with an `onclick` handler using the following method:

```
domConstruct.create('button', {
  ...
  value: someValue,
  onclick: this.onBtnClick
});
```

The `onBtnClick` method uses the value of the button element, and also calls another function:

```
onBtnClick: function() {
  var someVar = this.value // This button element's value property
  this.someFunc(someVar);
}

someFunc: function(arg) {
  ...
}
```

When executing `onclick`, it gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.someFunc is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onBtnClick
```

However, the button element's value could be correctly fetched by `this.value`. So it looks like in the `onBtnClick` method the `this` keyword only refers to the button element instead of the entire widget. Is there anyway to use both the button element's value as well as `this.someFunc` in `onBtnClick`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the [hitch](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) function in the dojo/_base/lang module when using "this" in callback functions. Here is how I use in my code to run the function "applyEdits" when clicking on a button:

```
import lang from "dojo/_base/lang";

domConstruct.create(
  "div",
  {
    class: "jimu-btn " + settingName,
    style: "margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;",
    onclick: lang.hitch(this, function (evt) {
      this.applyEdits(evt);
    })
  },
  container
);
```